# Docker container cannot connect to linked containers services

Tags: docker

I'm using Docker version 1.9.1 build a34a1d5 on an Ubuntu 14.04 server host and I have 4 containers: redis (based on alpine linux 3.2), mongodb (based on alpine linux 3.2), postgres (based on ubuntu 14.04) and the one that will run the application that connects to these other containers (based on alpine linux 3.2). All of the db containers expose their corresponding ports in the Dockerfile.

I did the modifications on the database containers so their services don't bind to the localhost IP but to all addresses. This way I would be able to connect to all of them from the app container.
For the sake of testing, I first ran the database containers and then the app one with a command like the following:

```
docker run --rm --name app_container --link mongodb_container --link redis_container --link postgres_container  -t localhost:5000/app_image
```

I enter the terminal of the app container and I verify that its /etc/hosts file contains the IP and names of the other containers. Then I am able to ping all the db containers. But I cannot connect to their ports to any of the db containers.

A simple: `telnet mongodb_container 27017` simply sits and waits forever, and the same happens if I try to connect to the other db containers. If I run the application, it also complains that it cannot connect to the specified db services.

**Important note:** I am able to telnet the corresponding ports of all the db containers from the host.

What might be happening?

**EDIT:** I'll include the run commands for the db containers:

```
docker run --rm --name mongodb_container -t localhost:5000/mongodb_image
docker run --rm --name redis_container -t localhost:5000/redis_image
docker run --rm --name postgres_container -t localhost:5000/postgres_image
```

Comment: Can you include the run commands of all these other containers? Did you expose the correct ports and use the `-p port:port` flags?

Comment: Try `nslookup mongodb_container` or `ping mongedb_container` to see if it is resolving the IP. The `--link` argument should write an entry in the host file inside your container enabling them to resolve.

Just for completeness... you can run a shell in the container like this:
`docker exec -it <CONTAINER_NAME> /bin/bash`

Comment: @cricket_007, sure, I added the run commands and I while I was testing, I stopped the mongo container and then added the `-p 27017:27017` in its run command, and it still failed to connect. And after double checking the Dockerfiles, I am exposing the correct ports.

Comment: @KevinBurdett, yes, from the app container, I can ping all of the other containers and their IP's are correctly resolved. Yup, I enter my app container using `docker exec -it app_container bash`.

Comment: I saw this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481530/postgres-to-ubuntu-docker-container-linking-not-working and the last comment of the OP was "Weird. Maybe 1.7.1 doesn't work well on Ubuntu 14.04? It's working for me now that I downgraded so I'm going to move on.". Perhaps I'm suffering the same effect?

Comment: Could you post one of your Dockerfiles (eg. PostgreSQL)? And why do you have '-t' in all your run commands?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the problem with telnet seems to be related to the telnet client on alpine linux since the following two commands showed me that the ports on the containers were open:

```
nmap -p27017 172.17.0.3
nc -vz 172.17.0.3 27017
```

Being focused mainly on the telnet command I issued, I believed that the problem was related to the ports being closed or something; and I overlooked the configuration file on the app that was being used to connect it to the services (it was the wrong filename), my bad.

All works fine now.