# Docker swarm containers can't connect out

Tags: docker, networking, docker-swarm

I've got a small docker swarm with three nodes.

```
$ sudo docker node ls
ID                            HOSTNAME                                     STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
jmsidw84mom3k9m4yoqc7rkj0     ip-172-31-a-x.region.compute.internal    Ready               Active                                  19.03.1
qg1njgopzgiainsbl2u9bmux4 *   ip-172-31-b-y.region.compute.internal   Ready               Active              Leader              19.03.1
yn9sj3sp5b3sr9a36zxpdt3uw     ip-172-31-c-z.region.compute.internal   Ready               Active                                  19.03.1
```

And I'm running three redis containers.

```
$ sudo docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                      PORTS
6j9mmnpgk5j4        redis              replicated          3/3                 172.31.m.n:5000/redis
```

But I can't get redis sentinel working between them - reading the logs it looks as though there are connection failures.

Just standing them up as three separate redis instances I've been testing connectivity and I can telnet from a shell on any host to the host IP of another node and it connects to the service running on the container. If I do the same from a shell on the container it can't connect out.

i.e.

```
[centos@172.31.a.x ~]$ telnet 172.31.b.y 6379
Trying 172.31.b.y...
Connected to 172.31.b.y.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
[centos@172.31.a.x ~]$ sudo docker exec -it 4d5abad441b8 sh
/ # telnet 172.31.14.12 6379
```

And then it hangs. Similarly I can't telnet to google.com on 443 from within a container but I can on the host. Curiously though, ping does get out of the container.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this blog help - https://medium.com/@mustafa.ileri/redis-clustering-with-redis-sentinel-on-docker-1090ab876f97 ?

Comment: In terms of this stack, no because I'm not using compose (I'm using ansible's docker_swarm_service module). But it's probably my next move to drop ansible and try compose if I can't resolve this.

Comment: Compose says `Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.` - that sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.

The redis side is a red herring, I can debug that now - I was mulling over that telnet isn't on the container (alpine linux) by default so there must be some connectivity, but I couldn't telnet to the webserver port it claimed it was downloading from as it installs.

Turns out there's something up with the version of the telnet client alpine linux installs - nmap and curl behave as expected.

Comment: Someone else hit this a few years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351833/docker-container-cannot-connect-to-linked-containers-services